# 401 on npm whoami when copying _authToken in .npmrc

Tags: npm

As stated to provide [npm authentication for deployment](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/118393368555/deploying-with-npm-private-modules), I tried copying my .npmrc file containing the `//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` line.

However, when I try `npm whoami` I get a 401, and `npm install` on my private modules also doesn't work.

I tried running `npm login` after on the same machine and everything worked. Then I changed the _authToken back to the original one that was failing, rather than the newly created one. It still worked after doing this. So clearly there is something going on with auth more than just the token. Does NPM keep track of authorized IPs or something else I'm unaware of? I'm trying to setup my deployment to be able to access my private repos.

Comment: I'm interested in the same issue, has anyone came up with solution?